# How to position a Div over the other content in the middle of the screen?

Tags: html, css

In my symfony html view, i'd like to open a pop up in front of the view over the other content on Button click. This is not really a problem, i just give my div `position: absolute` and `top: 80px`

But now i don't want my div to be always 80px from the top, but in the middle of the screen. So if i scroll down, it should be positioned further down as well, so it is still in the middle of the screen.
Do i have to use javascript for that or can i do this with html and css only?

Comment: Yes, you can just use css. You need some math, using the viewport width and height. Read up on using `vw` and `vh` in CSS. If you don't know the height of your div, you may also need `calc`.

Comment: nice that looks very good, thank you @ed2

Comment: Thanks, in that case I have put this as an answer so that you can flag it accordingly for future readers.

Comment: Could you remove the "symfony" tag please :) ? It's not a problem about Symfony or PHP, only front-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow the below code :-

```js
function openDialog(){
  const modalContainer  = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-container")[0];
  modalContainer.classList.remove('hide');
}

function closeDialog(){
  const modalContainer  = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-container")[0];
  modalContainer.classList.add('hide');
}
```

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

.container{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }

 .modal-container{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   top:0;
   z-index: 9999999;
   background-color: aliceblue;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;  
 }
 
 
 .hide{
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button onclick="openDialog()">Open   Dialog</button>
</div>

 <div  class="modal-container hide">
  <div class="modal-header"> Modal Header</div>
  <div class="modal-content"> Modal Content</div>
  <div class="modal-content"> <button onclick="closeDialog()">Close    Dialog</button></div>
</div>
```

it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You achieve that using css vh(viewport height) unit for height,

```
position: fixed;
top: 45vh; // As per your need
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just use css. You need some math, using the viewport width and height. Read up on using `vw` and `vh` in CSS. If you don't know the height of your div, you may also need `calc`.